# Access String Value from TempData from Script Tag inside View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to access string value from TempData from the script tag inside `.cshtml` file.

```
<script>  
    var FromComTaskLibType = '@TempData["FromComTaskLibType"]';
    console.log(FromComTaskLibType.toString())    
</script>
```

Using this, I am getting value as `AAAA` instead of getting like `'AAAA'`. I have called them with `.toString()`. Still it is not working.

In controller, I am assigning this value like this:

```
public ActionResult LoginFromCOM(string libType)
{                  
    TempData["FromComTaskLibType"] = libType;
    //...
}
```

Here value of `libType` is coming as `"AAAA"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using this, I am getting value as AAAA instead of getting like 'AAAA'.
> I have called them with .toString(). Still it is not working.

Well, you don't need to `convert to string` as `TempData` already a `string`. So you could try following way.

**Controller:**

```
public class AccessTempDataController : Controller
        {
            
            public ActionResult LoginFromCOM(string libType)
            {
                TempData["FromComTaskLibType"] = libType;
               return View();
            }
        }
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    var FromComTaskLibType = '@TempData["FromComTaskLibType"]';
    alert(FromComTaskLibType);
    console.log(FromComTaskLibType);
</script>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**If You Want This 'AAAA' Output:**

However, if you want your output as `'AAA'` with `single qoute` You have to parse the string into `JSON.stringify` then has to replace the double qoute into `single qoute` as following:

```
<script>
    var FromComTaskLibType = '@TempData["FromComTaskLibType"]';
    alert(JSON.stringify(FromComTaskLibType));

    var data = JSON.stringify(FromComTaskLibType);
    alert(data.replace(/"/g, '\''));
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `ViewBag` at .cshtml file parameter

Example:

```
@ViewBag.nameEntity
```

Comment: No, `tempData` can also be used.